How to write a JPA criteria query with dynamic duration in where clause?
I'm trying to translate the following SQL query into a JPA Criteria Query using CriteriaBuilder and Specifications.
SELECT *
FROM activity
WHERE date_start + duration * interval '1 minute' > current_timestamp;

date_start is a TIMESTAMP column.
duration is an INTEGER column representing the number of minutes.
In java types:
SingularAttribute<Activity, Integer> duration
SingularAttribute<Activity, ZonedDateTime> dateStart
Could someone help me structure this query properly in JPA Criteria?
I tried something like this:
specification = specification.and((root, query, builder) -> {
                 Expression<Integer> durationParam = root.get("duration");
                 Expression<ZonedDateTime> dateStart = root.get("dateStart");

                 Expression<ZonedDateTime> newDate = builder.function(
                     "DATEADD",
                     ZonedDateTime.class,
                     builder.literal("minute"), 
                     durationParam,             
                     dateStart                  
                 );

                 Expression<ZonedDateTime> currentDate = builder.function("GETDATE", ZonedDateTime.class);

                 return builder.lessThan(newDate, currentDate);
             });


In your SQL query you are comparing with greater than '>' but in query you are trying to fire builder.lessThan
So I think your last 2 statements should be ZonedDateTime currentDate = ZonedDateTime.now(); builder.greaterThan(newDate, currentDate);

Here is a working solution, but I'm not sure if it's ok.
if (criteria.getActive() != null) {
    specification = specification.and((root, query, builder) -> {
        HibernateCriteriaBuilder hb = (HibernateCriteriaBuilder) builder;
        JpaExpression<Duration> oneMinute = hb.durationScaled(root.get(Activity_.duration), Duration.ofMinutes(1));
        Expression<ZonedDateTime> result = hb.addDuration(root.get(Activity_.dateStart), oneMinute);
        if (criteria.getActive()) {
            return builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(result, ZonedDateTime.now());
        }

        return builder.lessThan(result, ZonedDateTime.now());
    });
}

